# image comparison using edges and textures

Tags: python, opencv

I am working with python and opencv on a piece of software which should compare two images and return as result a value representing their similarity.

I tried first with histograms, and then with SIFT and SURF but the first method is not localized while the second and the third are slow and do not fit very much with my datased content (mostly pictures of crowds).

I would avoid people detector, so I would like to apply some algorithm connected to edges and textures comparison. Cany you give some hints or online resource?

Comment: So you want to measure the similarity of images of crowds? What is important? Number of people? Color of clothes they are wearing? Facial expression?

Comment: I would like to know if the two images are likely to be related to the "same event" (e.g. buildings, crowds, and so on)

Comment: Ok, this could become difficult, because of changing type of objects, lightning conditions etc. I guess you could try to mix different criteria (histograms, keypoint descriptors etc.) for your result. Do you habe a large enough training dataset to test different kinds of classificators?

Comment: well, that's exactly what i have done so far...as i said above, i'm looking for something connected to edges and textures

Comment: Did you already have a look at HOG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting, although challenging problem!  Recently, I came across an article by the University of California, San Diego's [Vision Group](http://vision.ucsd.edu/) about classifying scenes of crowds.  Here is the link: [Urban Tribes: Analyzing Group Photos from a Social Perspective](http://vision.ucsd.edu/sites/default/files/urbantribes.pdf).

As you can see, there is no one-size-fits-all solution, but I would think that this should provide you a good place to start from.

Comment: hi thanks for you link! yes, the topic is rather challenging and I have done a lot of stuff with it..concerning my original questin: can you recommend a way to compare edges obtained for example with sobel filter?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know anything about Edge Comparison, sorry!  I found [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970183/image-comparison-edges-shape-only-no-color-how-to-distinguish-cat-from-cat), maybe those links can help you?  I don't really know how you would compare edges?  Maybe if you could provide an example of two images being compared in this manner I could understand the problem better?  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is a general image classification framework.
Try googling: image classification, scene classification, image Indexing and Retrieval.

In most cases, you'll have to use a multimodal descriptor. Use color, texture, entropy, keypoints, edge histograms.

You can read [this](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01431160600746456) and try [that](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~bilmdg/bilvideo-7/).