# Person and vehicle recognition

Tags: image-processing, opencv, artificial-intelligence, computer-vision, image-recognition

I am looking for a library (open source or not) to analyize photos and determine if there are vehicles and or people in the images. I am not looking for facial recognition or vehicle classification. Just the ability to determine with some percentage certainty that a vehicle and or person is contained in images taken periodically.

I can provide a significant  number (1000s) of photos to train the system.

*Edit 1*

I expect to supply photos to a training system, and understand that the quality of the detection system will depend on my training photos. What I am after I guess, is something like Numenta's Image recognition demo software (nicely packaged), but with a more flexible api (training and calling the system from a http api would be nice).

Are there any implementations of the OpenCV haar system that have been wrapped up nicely into a windows program?

Comment: Maybe better on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV is definitely one of the best choices you can start with.

**But**, note that what you want to achieve is really far off than what you may think. It's not like a library for, let's say JPEG compression, when you need a day to understand and use. OpenCV is a collection of tools and algorithms for scientists and engineers to research new ways in image recognition; you may need a significant amount of time and energy to accomplish your task.

Comment: I will edit my question to reflect what I am really after. A self contained training system. I expect to supply the images. But if there is a software package with a nice interface (http api or something) that I can use, that would be a nice fit.

Comment: For this question, the answer is easy: there aren't anywhere such libraries/training systems. Image processing is at the cutting edge of technology, so you have to do for yourself some research - nobody-s gonna give you such a system.

Answer (score 0):

Use search terms like "machine learning", "neural network", "image classification", library or package and your favorite programming language. 
Could be anything from scikit-learn to Weka.

Also see here: [Image Classification Algorithms Using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327856/image-classification-algorithms-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV can provide to you the training stuff in Haar cascades to detect. [Here](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) is a tutorial for haartraining. Note that is about the old program haartraining, not the new program traincascade (supports multi-threading, a quick search should show to you how to use, it is almost the same usage).

Answer (score 0):

A first approach similar to Human detection is to learn linear support vector machine classifier on histogram of oriented gradient descriptors. [Here](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf) is the base article from [INRIA](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/).
Opencv provide implementations of HoG, linear SVM, and evaluation framework.